# change Brightcove video link to Https

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, https, brightcove

We are accessing the videos and still images using the Brightcove API. However the links to video and images come out as Http.  example below

```
http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/e1/pd/16116593001/106593001_20213001_th-50ca1eeae4b00202ed60-1471893001.jpg?pubId=16435545593001
```

Is there any way to force the brighcove to return the links as https ?

This is because the website is on https and its displaying images/videos from brightcove cloud. It would be much easier if the images/videos are served up on https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to contact Brightcove about this. The file is on a CDN only configured for HTTP, so there's nothing you can directly do.

Comment: @BlindBandit, were you able to get this working after talking to BrightCove?